# not by all or not by any

Tags: determiners

ABC is a communal obligation that, if, is **not discharged by all**, then every individual stands criminal.

Here what do we infer by **not discharged by all**?

> Some have done it and some haven't.

OR

> None have done it.

Shouldn't we say:  **not discharged by any**?

In short, if we say: *It was not done by all*. What does it mean?

> No one did it.

OR

> Some did it and some didn't.

Comment: Logically/semantically, negating ***not*** applies to ***all***, not ***discharged***. That's to say, you should understand it as meaning *if NOT ALL [the people] discharge the obligation* rather than *if all the people do NOT DISCHARGE the obligation.*.

Comment: You can't tell, because "not all" (< x) includes "none" (0).

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, *not discharged by all* and *not discharged by any* amount to the same thing.

The statement declares that unless all (=every individual) discharge/s the obligation, then every individual (=all) will be regarded as criminal.

To change **all** to **any** would mean:

If any (individual or individuals) fail/s to discharge the obligation, then all will be regarded as criminal.

So which ever construction you prefer, every single person concerned has to fulfill the obligation to prevent all of them being regarded as criminally liable.